# Differentiation on the conditional variables of a probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, parameterization, derivative

I have been questioning how to calculate the partial derivatives of a conditional probability function with respect to its parameters. 
Assume $x$ is data and $\theta$ is a parameter(s). If I have a probability $p(x|\theta)$ in an explicit form, it will be easy to derive its (logarithmic) derivatives $\nabla_\theta \log p(x|\theta)$. 
My question is, if I change the parameters using another set of parameters $\phi$ as $\theta = f(\phi)$, how can I derive the derivatives with respect to $\phi$, that is, $\nabla_\phi \log p(x|\phi)$ ? Should I just substitute as $p(x|\theta) = p(x|f(\phi))$ and re-define this as $p(x|\phi)$ ?

Comment: Apply the Chain Rule.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the comment. Is it sufficient to apply the chain rule? The change of parameters might probably transform the function such that $p(x|\phi) = p(x|\theta)|d\theta/d\phi|$, though I'm not confident.

Comment: The parameter is merely a numerical name for a distribution.  A reparameterization changes the name but refers to the same distribution, which is not thereby altered in any way.